# workflow "update item" help

Tags: workflow

I set up a workflow that let's a user create and populate a word document using an input form from a custom list. I followed Todd's blog post to achieve this: 
http://ochoco.blogspot.com/2009/04/automatically-create-word-documents.html

After the form in the custom list "documents" is submited and the word document is generated in "certificate" document library, I want to create a second workflow step that will update the record in custom list "documents" to display a hyperlink to the word document.

To do this, I'm using "Update item in *_*" to place a hyperlink within my "LINKTOWORDDOC" field but I can't get the correct url to display.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The create action will output a variable that contains the item ID value.  You can use that ID to look up URL information from the library, build a dynamic string and update the list with that URL.